# Check all the values of an object then if the values is empty it will return what is the key of that empty value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object store in useState, i just want to find out which of this keys have a value of empty and return the key of that emply value

```
const [projectInfo, setProjectInfo] = useState({
projectName: '',
projectDescription: '',
projectCreator: '',
})
const [error, setError] = useState({})

const handleCheckValidation = () => {
if(!projectInfo.projectName){
 setError((prevState) => ({
                            ...prevState,
                            projectNameError: true,
                          }))
```

Thanks!

Comment: please update your code, what you have tried intially

Comment: I want to use this to validate each of the keys the other options is check every keys by using if state but I'm hoping to find a much better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can filter the empty value, it will give you array item of empty value,

```
   const isEmptyValue = Object.keys(projectInfo).filter((item) => projectInfo[item] === '')
    
    output: ["projectName", "projectDescription", "projectCreator"]
```

or if the object is dynamic, and you are getting it through props or api

```
const [projectInfo, setProjectInfo] = useState(Object.keys(yourObject).filter((item) => yourObject[item] === ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const object = {
  projectName: '',
  projectDescription: '',
  projectCreator: '',
}

const nullKeys = []

Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
  if(!object[key]){
    nullKeys.push(key)
  }
})

console.log(nullKeys)
```

Comment: This will consider zero numbers, false booleans, empty arrays also as an empty field. I'm not sure if we need to consider this